# Yii Booster popover over text rather than button

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, yii, yii-extensions

Yii booster [documentation](http://yii-booster.clevertech.biz/basicFeatures/pages/view/bootstrap.html#popover) shows how to make a popover over a button. I want to create one over an anchor element rather than a button. Essentially I want to combine the popover with Yii's [tooltip](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/javascript.html#tooltips). Does anyone know how to do this?

This is the code for the pop-over:

```
$this->widget(
'bootstrap.widgets.TbButton',
array(
    'label' => 'Top popover',
    'type' => 'primary',
    'htmlOptions' => array(
        'data-title' => 'A Title',
        'data-placement' => 'top',
        'data-content' => "And here's some amazing content. It's very engaging. right?",
        'data-toggle' => 'popover'
    ),
));
```

If there was a way of altering this to not render a button, but just an anchor the problem would be solved, but I can't find anything in the code that I can use to do this.

**Update**

Following Sergey's answer, here's what I've put:

```
echo CHtml::Link("$detail->text", null, 
array(
'rel' => 'popover',
'data-trigger' => "hover",
'data-title' => "$header",
'data-content' => "$body"
));
```

This is close to what I need, but for some reason the hove doesn't work, only the click and also only the content get's displayed not the title.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use CHtml:

```
<?php echo CHtml::Link('<i class="icon-info-sign"></i>', null, [
    'rel' => 'popover',
    'data-trigger' => 'hover',
    'data-title' => 'Your title',
    'data-content' => 'Your content',
])?>
```

[image]

**Update:**
For Bootstrap 2.3.2 :

```
<?php Yii::app()->clientScript->registerScript("", "$('.ipopover').popover();", CClientScript::POS_READY) ?>
<?php echo CHtml::Link('<i class="icon-info-sign"></i>', null, array(
    'class' => 'ipopover',
    'data-trigger' => 'hover',
    'data-title' => 'Your title',
    'data-content' => 'Your content',
))?>
```

Comment: This is close to what I need, but I can't quite get it to work like you can. I'll post what I've put above incase I've put something wrong.

Comment: Hi Sergey, any ideas on why my code isn't working? I've only made minor adjustments from yours and one was entirely necessary as my version of PHP would not accept the square brackets for an array. Any help much appreciated.

Comment: Updated the post for Bootstrap 2.3.2

Comment: I upgraded to the latest version of Yii Booster, but it now throws the error 'CClientScript and its behaviors do not have a method or closure named "registerClientScript"'

Comment: It gives a popover as before, but still no title and it still doesn't trigger on hover, only on click.

Comment: My code works well. [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MgcDU/7343/) Try to write html + js [Bootstrap docs](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/javascript.html#popovers)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37986/discussion-between-goose-and-sergey-bulavkin)